# Calling jsp functions

Tags: jsp, struts, jsp-tags

i have a jsp page in which there are three functions on `onclick` event.
i want that on `onclick` of `submitformFinal()` function , it should check whether its `true` or `false` and then depending on outcome, it should execute the other two functions.
    my `onlick` functions are:-

```
onclick="javascript:changeAction('save');checkMultiSelects();submitformFinal();" />
```

Comment: Why don't you put them inside submitformFinal() then??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this

```
 function changeAction(action)//value pass to the variable action
        {

        if()//your condition is true
        {
        return checkMultiSelects();
        }
        return false;
        }


    function checkMultiSelects()
    {
    if()//true
    {
    return submitformFinal();
    }
    return false;
    }


    function submitformFinal()
    {
    if()//true
    {
    return true;
    }
    return false;
    }
```

and use this code on jsp page

```
onclick="javascript:return changeAction('save');" />
```

Comment: as per your need, this is the simplest way to do. If you will elaborate you problem, then i may help you. Submit your code with the question.

Comment: i have updated my code, have a look, if you still face any problem, then let me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest wrapping the other two functions onto your initial function and call them from there.

For example:

```
function changeAction('string') {
   // do some stuff
   // return true or false
   if (action==true) {
       checkMultiSelects();
       submitformFinal();
   } else {
       return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot do it this way? More information would help with a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.

```
if(actionReturn==true){
     callMethod1();
     callmethod2();
    }else{
    return false; 
    }
```